# DRF perform_create set m2m field depend on FK

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I got models:

**USER**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company,  on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                blank=True, null=True)
```

**Product**
Product can be in dif companies.

```
 company = models.ManyToManyField(Company, blank=True)
```

My case is , When I create product I want to set M2M field depend on my user.company (FK)

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
   company = self.request.user.company
   serializer.save(company=company)
```

Got error now:

```
TypeError 
'Company' object is not iterable
```

Comment: I did it with 
`obj = serializer.save()
obj.company.add(self.request.user.company)`

Answer (score 0):

You must use real instance for foreign key field. use company id for define company object

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
   company_id = self.request.user.company.id
   company = Company.objects.filter(id=company_id).first()
   serializer.save(company=company)
```

Comment: if DEBUG==True, write you log from browser page that i can check you request object or print(self.request.user.company) and write what it print in terminal

Comment: print give me id all good, so self.request.user.company took it.

Comment: okay, try this ```company_id = self.request.user.company
   company = Company.objects.filter(id=company_id).first()```

Comment: now this one `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Company`

Comment: please, write for me what terminal print after ```print(company)```, now i quess you try define company field as int

Comment: I did it like
`obj = serializer.save()
obj.company.add(self.request.user.company)`